# How to convert two varchar columns to time and substract the hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve this problem and I really appreciate any help or direction.

I have a Mysql database with a events table where I have two columns with data type as varchar and the names are time_start and time_end

The values are stored as string in 24hours format: 16:00:00 for example

For example purpose image the result of select * from events is:

```
time_start time_end
13:00:00   14:00:00
```

How to convert those strings to time and substract (time_end - time_start) resulting in 1h

Tks for any help

Comment: Can you give a better example where the difference is not exactly one hour?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the difference easily by using `time_to_sec()` or `timestampdiff()`:

```
select time_to_sec(time(time_end)) - time_to_sec(time(time_start))
```

This gives the time in seconds.  If you want integer hours, divide by 3600:

```
select floor( (time_to_sec(time(time_end)) - time_to_sec(time(time_start))) / (60 * 60)) as hours
```

Or, if you really just want to subtract the hour portion, you can do:

```
select left(time_end, 2) - left(time_start, 2)
```

MySQL will convert the values to numbers, because of the arithmetic operation.